# Hiding symbol visibility while building a shared lib

Tags: c, gcc, visibility, ld, symbols

I have multiple objects files (lets say `obj1.o`, `obj2.o`) with which i am building a shared library (`libapp.so`). All associated objects so not had visibility flag as hidden when they were built, but in final so (`libapp.so`, see below), if i use visibility flag as `hidden`, will it hide all internal functions from outside libraries to use?

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden obj1.o obj2.o -o libapp.so
```

---

EDIT:

As wRAR mentioned, i tried using versions cript to hide all symbol on final shared library. version script was written like-

file:libapp.version

```
{
    local: *;
};
```

and i built my shared library as:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC obj1.o obj2.o -o libapp.so -Wl,--version-script=libapp.version
```

Even after putting all symbol as local, i still can see in nm that all symbols are present. What i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`-fvisibility` is a compile-time option, so it has no effect at the link time. You can write a version script for `ld` to hide symbols at the link time.

Comment: I tried version script just as you mentioned. See my attempt on EDIT section of my question. Please let me know if i had used script in wrong way.